# Timezone in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

After concatenate date and time field, and result put in new datetime field get 2 hours more than necessary

Example:

```py
date = fields.Date(string = 'date', select=True)
time = fields.Many2one('period.time', string='Available time',select=True)
date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Datetime', compute="_compute")
description = fields.Char(string = 'Descroption', compute="_compute")

@api.onchange('date', 'time') #time is 08:00:00
def _compute(self):
    self.date_time = "%s %s:00" % (self.date,self.time.name)
    self.description = "%s %s:00" % (self.date,self.time.name)
```

date_time (Datetime) 2017-04-10 10:00:00  --> Wrong

description (Char) 2017-04-10 08:00:00   --> Correct

How fix this issue?

Comment: Time is which type of field in odoo ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. time is Many2one

Comment: Can you write full code of your fields ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. added i  post...

Comment: Can you write class definition of my.time class ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.  https://postimg.org/image/ajm1df46b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not wrong from odoo side because odoo save date in UTC.When the user request a date odoo convert the date from the database to the timezone of the users.

so if you go to the database you will find that the field is stored `date = 2017-04-10 08:00:00` but in the view the date is converted to timezone of the user in your case is converted to `2017-04-10 10:00:00`

so before saving the date make sure that you convert the value to `UTC` datetime i mean don't save `2017-04-10 08:00:00` to date_time but save `2017-04-10 06:00:00`

EDITS :
Try this i hope it work id didn't use it but i think it will work if there is any error just put it here:

```
# first import 
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

class ...
    ...
    date = fields.Date(string = 'date', select=True)
    time = fields.Many2one('period.time', string='Available time',select=True)
    date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Datetime', compute="_compute")
    description = fields.Char(string = 'Descroption', compute="_compute")
    ...
    ...

    @api.onchange('date', 'time') #time is 08:00:00
    def _compute(self):
        # by default timezone = UTC
        user_time_zone = pytz.UTC

        if self.env.user.partner_id.tz :
            # change the timezone to the timezone of the user
            user_time_zone = pytz.timezone(self.env.user.partner_id.tz)

        # create time string
        concat_time = "%s %s:00" % (self.date,self.time.name)
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

        # create a time object
        user_time = datetime.strptime(concat_time, fmt)

        # define the timezone of the time object
        # here i think the first line is enougth
        user_time = user_time_zone.localize(user_time)
        user_time.replace(tzinfo=user_time_zone)

        # you can get the time in UTC like this 
        print "This is what you need to save in database %s ", user_time.astimezone(pytz.UTC).strftime(fmt)

        self.date_time = user_time.astimezone(pytz.UTC).strftime(fmt)
```

Comment: i used a lot of code you can make it more less see  openerp.fields.Datetime  class you can see how the convert happen

Answer (score 0):

In the odoo class datetime you can find for the class Datetime the method,

```
def context_timestamp(record, timestamp):
```

You can use this method to convert you Datetime in UTC to the timestamp of the user like this.

You need import this 2 packages

```
import datetime as DT
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT as DF
```

and after do this.

```
date = fields.Date(string = 'date', select=True)
time = fields.Many2one('period.time', string='Available time',select=True)
date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Datetime', compute="_compute")
description = fields.Char(string = 'Descroption', compute="_compute")

@api.onchange('date', 'time') #time is 08:00:00
def _compute(self):
       date_utc = DT.datetime.strptime(self.date, DF)
       date_tz = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, date_utc)
       self.description = date_tz.strftime(DF)
```